# WebLogic stopManagedWeblogic.sh script prompts for username and password for shutting down managed server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

The managed server created in the WebLogic 12c environment is prompting for the username and password when stopping the managed server with stopManagedWeblogic.sh script even when boot.properties file is present with correct credentials.

The boot.properties file configured in some other accessible location whose path is specified using `-Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile` java option

I've observed below strange behavior

- It's not prompting for username and password when starting the
  managed server with startManagedWeblogic.sh script(I suppose it's
  looking into boot.properties file).
- It's not prompting for username and password when starting and stopping admin server

It's prompting for username and password only in case of managed server shutdown using stopManagedWeblogic.sh script.

Is passwordless managed server shutdown not supported in WebLogic ?, as I don't want username and password specified as a parameter to stop script.

Comment: I experience the same behaviour. Try stopping the whole stack at once using the ${domain_home}/bitools/bin/stop.cmd instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is identified as a bug in WebLogic 12c

The `stopManagedWeblogic.sh` implementation logic ignores `-Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile` option and checks the boot.properties file inside `<domain_home>/servers/<managed_server_name>/security/boot.properties` location, if boot.properties file is not present in this location, it prompts for admin server credentails.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and could resolve it by trying the following:

1. create the directory <domain_home>/servers/<managed_server>/security
2. create boot.properties in the above directory with the below values:
   username=<username>
   password=<password>

Now, start/stopManagedWeblogic.sh would work without prompting for credentials.

Comment: whats the use of -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile option then. Is it a bug with WebLogic?

Comment: As per my understanding, WLST connect command reads boot.properties from the security folder corresponding to the server in question ( in this case, the managed server ).

Comment: But I don't have the boot.properties file in security folder, and weblogic support any location for boot.properties file with the use of -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile option. Refer [How a Server Uses a Boot Identity File at Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/server_start/overview.html#wp1068997)

Comment: Yes; at startup, boot properties provided using -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile will be considered. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with stop command.

Comment: Its not considered only in case of managed server stop. For admin server stop it works. It seems to be a bug in weblogic

Comment: I could not stop admin server by using -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile. I did the following: 1. Removed boot.properties from AdminServer's security folder. 2. Exported JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=location of boot.properties" 3. Invoked stopManagedWebLogic.sh AdminServer. It prompted me for username and password to connect

Comment: Invoke stopWeblogic.sh to stop admin server and not stopManagedWeblogic.sh

Comment: Yes Vivek. Even with start/stopWeblogic.sh, I get password prompts; even when JAVA_OPTIONS is set for -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile.

Comment: No. With start script, it doesn't prompt for credentials, there must be some problem with you boot.properties/ java option configuration